# How to make IntelliJ run my program in a terminal emulator?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, terminal, intellij-14

My application depends on there being a TTY, so I cannot run it with an Application configuration. Is it possible to have IntelliJ run my application in a terminal emulator instead?

Comment: have you got a minimal example I could try in IJ?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch sure: https://gist.github.com/rightfold/4035649da27d25698cb9

Comment: just looking at it, one question: in the finally block `Seq("sh", "-c", s"stty '$originalSettings' < /dev/tty").!` you don't need the `< /dev/tty`, that's right?

Comment: Mind pasting the relevant code snippet that requires TTY to the question itself? Else it's a fine candidate for closing as off-topic.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski This question isn't off-topic. Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are explicitly on-topic. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

I guess, your intent is to debug the code. If so, I found a solution. I did the following (all on OS X 10.10):

- in the terminal (separate process) I compiled your file `scalac Test.scala`
- I started the program from the terminal with the following debug flags: `scala -J-Xdebug -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 org.rightfold.ahhaha.Main`
- in IJ I created a run/debug configuration of type *remote* with the default parameters, notably port 5005
- I set a breakpoint in the sourcecode
- started the remote debug configuration, it attached to the code in the terminal and stopped where I had set the breakpoint. I could inspect variables and so on

IJ has a terminal of it's own (View/Tool Windows/Terminal). I haven't tried it there, but that should work as well as it's a tty.

Hope that helps